# Migrating from Flow to TypeScript: $Call<F, T...> equivalent in TS?

Tags: typescript, flowtype

Flow has the handy [`$Call<F, T...>` utility type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-call) that can get the return type of calling the function of type F with the (optional) first argument as type T, second argument and so on. So we can do:

```js
type First = <T>(Array<T>) => T | void;
type ShouldBeOptionalString = $Call<First, Array<string>>; // ShouldBeOptionalString is string | void
```

Can TypeScript achieve the equivalent functionality? I know the [`ReturnType<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypet,) provided by TypeScript, but it can't calculate the return type base on the argument type:

```ts
type First = <T>(arg0: Array<T>) => T | void;
type WhatWillThisBe = ReturnType<First>; // WhatWillThisBe will be unknown
```

I tried rolling out my own version of ReturnType which tries to infer the return type with given arguments, but had no luck:

```ts
type CallWithArgsReturnType<T extends (...args: any) => any, A extends Array<any>> = T extends ((...args: A) => infer R) ? R : never;
type ShouldBeOptionalString = CallWithArgsReturnType<First, [Array<string>]>; // ShouldBeOptionalString will be unknown
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe to achieve something like this, you will have to make the type generic, and I guess a separate generic for every argument:

```
type First<T = any> = (arg0: T[]) => T | void;

type WhatWillThisBe = ReturnType<First<string>>; // string | void
```

If you also want the function to be generic, which I understand, you can do this:

```
type First<T = any> = <U extends T>(arg0: Array<U>) => U | void;

type WhatWillThisBe = ReturnType<First<string>>;  // string | void
```

Comment: Thanks for providing this solution, but the type I want to is from code where I have no controls on, it's from another library, exposing a type of function generic.